# tcl multithreading: best way to call function multiple times in a loop

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I want to create a thread for each call to a function in a loop. The callee function  is in the same namespace as the caller function but the callee function, during its execution, makes calls to functions from a different namespace.

I'm new to tcl and have been looking around at other SO multithreading solutions, but they seem to rely on having the callee proc itself embedded in the thread which I am trying to avoid.

I also am limited to Thread 2.7.3 so thread pools are unfortunately not an option.

I am also considering creating multiple subprocesses that can run in parallel, whichever is easier, but I want to know the best/easiest way to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

```
proc process_all_scenarios_multithreaded {results_folder} {

    package require Thread 2.7.3
    set curr_dir [pwd]
    cd $results_folder

    foreach scenario $scenario_list {           
        #package require dai                
        set sname $scenario'
        puts "Scenario: $sname"          
        set sdir "$curr_dir/$results_folder/$sname"
        puts "Results from: $sdir"          
        set status SUCCESS
        set id [thread::create -joinable]
        puts "*** Started thread $id"
        thread::send -async $id "extract_system_kpis $sname $status $sdir"
        lappend threadIds $id       
    }

    # Wait until all other threads are finished
    foreach id $threadIds {
        thread::join $id
    }
}
```

Comment: Stuck without thread pools? I guess that also means you don't have modern Tcl…

Comment: I can try thread pools but the application I'm interfacing with is support multithreading up to Thread package 2.7.3. The platform is installed with tcl version 8.6

Comment: Tcl threads are isolated from each other; think of each one as running in its own interp. You need to define/package require everything you need in each thread when it's created.

Comment: ok I see. so assuming I encapsulate the main function extract_system_kpis in a thread wrapper, that is fine but when it makes a call to another function in a difference namespace, how will that work?

Comment: Namespaces aren't really relevant. The other function has to be defined in the thread too in order to be called.

Comment: (Then you call it just like always; fully qualified name, using `namespace path` to add a namespace to the search path for commands, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, so if I want to call the function from another place without using multithreading, is that something that's limited?

Answer (score 0):

To simulate a thread pool, you've got to think in terms of

1. making workers, that
2. communicate with the master to pick up work packets,
3. carry out the work, and then
4. send the results back to the master before picking up the next work item.

You scale the number of workers with the resources you wish to allocate to the pool. Communications can be by any mechanism you want, but using `thread::send` works well between threads, and between processes you send Tcl lists via pipes or sockets. Tcl supports bidirectional pipes so it's pretty easy to do it that way.

Sending a message over a pipe just is a matter of doing:

```
puts $pipe [list ...]
flush $pipe
```

Receiving is a touch more complicated because you want to read lines until you have a complete list (according to `info complete`).

```
set accumulator ""
while {1} {
    append accumulator [gets $pipe] "\n"
    if {[info complete $accumulator]} {
        process $accumulator
        set accumulator ""
    } elseif {[eof $pipe]} {
        break
    }
}
```

You probably want to `eval` the received message and send back the result code, the result message, and the `$::errorInfo` as a built triple so that errors get propagated to where you can see them.

Comment: I've left a lot of details out. Thread pools hide a lot of the low level details from you.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to create a thread pool. I simply want to call a proc multiple times in a forloop using multithreading without wrapping the proc in the thread wrapper, because I intend to call that function elsewhere. I'm ok with running the proc using multiple processes but I'm having trouble where to start.